# flask/jinja2- how to reference variables inside of a "src" url_for

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, jinja2

I'm trying to source an image based on the session variable "user_id".

`<img src="{{urlfor('static', filename='images/budget_charts/{{session['user_id']}}.png')}}">`

The Error:

```
jinja2.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: expected token ',', got 'user_id'
```

My hypothesis on why this is happening is because the single quotes used to reference user_id are messing with the way it's parsed. However, I have no idea how to properly reference this without throwing an error.

Answer (score 0):

You are nesting single quotation marks and curly braces, so it cannot be properly parsed.

Try:

```
{% set file_name = "images/budget_charts/{{session['user_id']}}.png" %}

<img src="{{ url_for('static', filename=file_name) }}">
```

Notice there are no `''` inside other `''`, and no `{{}}` inside other `{{}}`

Answer (score 0):

Try `<img src="{{url_for('static', filename=f'images/budget_charts/{session[\'user_id\']}.png')}}">.`
You cannot use varibles with nested `{{ }}` tag